# Primefaces ajax Inplace save data

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have one Problem with the inplace Tag from JSF Primefaces

Here is a code snippet

```
<h:form >
 <p:inplace id="ajaxInplace" editor="true">  
   <p:inputText value="#{productService.instance.productName}"required="true"     label="text"/>     
 </p:inplace>
</h:form>
```

after the I press the confirmation button of the ajax inplace i want to store the changed data to my database. i have a method productService.updateInstance() to do this. but how can i call this method after the changes has been made?

thank you and kind regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `<p:ajax event="save"`

> save and cancel are two provided ajax behaviors events you can use to
>   hook-in the editing process.

```
 <p:inplace id="ajaxInplace" editor="true">  
   <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{productService.handleSave}" update="someThing" />
   <p:inputText value="#{productService.instance.productName}" required="true"     label="text"/>     
 </p:inplace>
```

Where `handleSave` looks like this

```
public void handleSave() {
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: thank you that helped.
but now i have the problem that the update just works once. i can not edit the text a second time again

Comment: strange , try playing with the `update` of the ajax maybe , like this : `update="ajaxInplace"`

Comment: <h:form id="description">
<p:inplace id="ajaxInplace" editor="true">
   <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{productService.updateInstance}" update="description" />
   <p:inputTextarea value="#{productService.instance.description}"                            required="true"label="text"/>
</p:inplace>
</h:form>

i also use a form tag, becaus without the form tag no changes are made

Comment: i did so but this did not change the behaviour. it eveen does not call the updateInstance method whenn i try to change it a second time

Comment: I guess you better ask a new question with my current solution but with the new problem

Comment: Fun fact, JSF Bean Validations like @NotNull does not work when invoked like this